# How to draw circles on random position in view borders

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Help me please to catch how to draw circles on random position in view borders.

Red View options

```
.background(Color.red)
.padding(40)
```

Circles:

```
var body: some View
{    
Circle()
.strokeBorder(Color.blue, lineWidth: 2.0, antialiased: true)
.frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
.overlay(Text(title))
}
```

I try to add circles on red view in random position using .position option, but you can see its not working:

[image: circles]

The main problem is how to know width and height of red view on any device and set .position of circles.

Comment: Whats wrong with Geometry Reader?

Comment: Thanks, i will try to learn and apply it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GeometryReader for reading the size of View, like in the example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            
            ForEach(0...50, id:\.self) { index in
                
                CirclesView(index: index)
                    .offset(x: CGFloat.random(in: 0.0...proxy.size.width), y: CGFloat.random(in: 0.0...proxy.size.height))
                
            }
            
        }
        .background(Color.red)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        
    }
    
}

struct CirclesView: View {
    
    let index: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Circle()
            .strokeBorder(Color.blue, lineWidth: 2.0, antialiased: true)
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            .overlay(Text(String(describing: index)))
    }
    
}
```

### Update:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            
            ForEach(0...50, id:\.self) { index in
                
                CirclesView(index: index, offset: logicalFunction(size: proxy.size))
  
            }
            
        }
        .background(Color.red)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        
    }
    
    func logicalFunction(size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        
        // Do your works here!
        
        let width: CGFloat = CGFloat.random(in: 0.0...size.width)
        let height: CGFloat = CGFloat.random(in: 0.0...size.height)
        
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        
    }
    
}

struct CirclesView: View {
    
    let index: Int
    let offset: CGSize
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Circle()
            .strokeBorder(Color.blue, lineWidth: 2.0, antialiased: true)
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            .overlay(Text(String(describing: index)))
            .offset(offset)
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: Help me please once more time, in code after "GeometryReader { proxy in" i try to insert logical staff to calculate positions of circles, but xcode says "Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'" when i try to call my function. Where can i append my func with logic using proxy data?