# SwiftUI, create a circle for each CGpoint in Array

Tags: swift, swiftui, shapes

I have an array of CGPoint and I'm trying to draw a little circle for each `CGPoint` location in this array (Using SwiftUI).

I have tried different approaches but have not been successful, I'm looking for some help.

my array : CGPoint is called "allFaceArray"

first try(doesn't working) throws an error : `Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'CGPoint' conform to 'Hashable'`

```
struct FaceFigure : View {
    @ObservedObject var ce : CameraEngine
    var size: CGSize
    var body: some View {
        if !ce.allFaceArray.isEmpty{
            ZStack{
                
                ForEach(ce.allFaceArray, id: \.self) { point in
                    Circle().stroke(lineWidth: 2.0).fill(Color.green)
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

second try I make a custom shape

```
struct MakeCircle: Shape {
    var arrayViso: [CGPoint]
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        for punti in arrayViso{
            
            let radius = 2
            path.addArc(
                center: punti,
                radius: CGFloat(radius),
                startAngle: Angle(degrees: 0),
                endAngle: Angle(degrees: 360),
                clockwise: true)
          
        }
        return path
    }
}
```

and I use it like this:

```
struct FaceFigure : View {
    @ObservedObject var ce : CameraEngine
    var size: CGSize
    var body: some View {
        if !ce.allFaceArray.isEmpty{
            ZStack{
               MakeCircle(arrayViso: ce.allFaceArray)
                   .stroke(lineWidth: 2.0)
                  .fill(Color.green)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but like this every points is connect each other with a line I don't know why...

thanks for the help

Comment: I answered almost same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68550718/14998134

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your second approach, you can create a separate path for each point in your array and add them to the path you already defined as `var path = Path()`. This way your second approach would work fine

```
struct MakeCircle: Shape {
    var arrayViso: [CGPoint]
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        for punti in arrayViso{
            var circle = Path()
            let radius = 2

            circle.addArc(
                center: punti,
                radius: CGFloat(radius),
                startAngle: Angle(degrees: 0),
                endAngle: Angle(degrees: 360),
                clockwise: true)

            path.addPath(circle)
        }
        return path
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you find `Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'CGPoint' conform to 'Hashable'`, making `CGPoint` conform to `Hashable` would be one way to solve it.

Please use this extension and re-try your first try:

```
extension CGPoint: Hashable {
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(x)
        hasher.combine(y)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain about hasher and combine please? What it is meaning `hasher.combine(x)`? , Is it the only way?

Comment: [SE-0206 Hashable Enhancements](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0206-hashable-enhancements.md)

Answer (score 2):

The first method can be used. Although you can't directly call `ForEach()` for CGPoint arrays. Instead you can use `ForEach` with a `Range<T>` like follows

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var allFaceArray = [
        CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
        CGPoint(x: 30, y: 50),
        CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100),
        CGPoint(x: 100, y: 500),
    ]
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(0..<allFaceArray.count) { x in //<- Passing the count of the array as a range
                Circle().stroke(lineWidth: 2.0).fill(Color.green)
                    .position(allFaceArray[x])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the above code is,
[image]